# Why gradle does not sync successfully

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When I want to build my project in android studio, it gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.room:room:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

This is my gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my gradle Module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
android {
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hooman.showimage"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
def lifeCycleExtensionVersion = '1.1.1'
def supportVersion = '28.0.0'
def retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
def glideVersion = '4.11.0'
def rxJavaVersion = '2.1.1'
def roomVersion = '2.3.0'
def navVersion = '2.3.4'
def preferencesVersion = '1.1.1'
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //My libraries
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room:$roomVersion"


    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$navVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preferencesVersion"
    //End My libraries
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

These 2 gradles work fine in kotlin but in java they have problem
I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything.
Where did I make a mistake?
Why these gradles sync in kotlin project well but they have problem in Java?
What should I do?

Comment: hey bro, if you are in iran, check your vpn connection :)

Comment: I have checked that. It works fine

Comment: yet still have your problem ?

Comment: @ MohammadMirshahbazi Yes

Comment: try this : repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        
    }

Comment: @ MohammadMirshahbazi still does not work

Comment: I found out this line has error: annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"

Comment: set roomVersion = '1.1.1' and try !

Comment: @ MohammadMirshahbazi No, it's not work too

Comment: Android studio can't download room library. I don't know why. My VPN works fine, all libraries have been downloaded but that one didn't

Comment: try to invalid cache and restart android studio, then try.

Comment: if that not work make new project and just add room and try it .

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the version of room to 2.2.5

Comment: Nothing changes and still shows me that error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case and the solution was I had missing mavenCentral() in buildscript repositories,

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    //
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrade to 2.2.6 and use it as:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion'
```

Also try making your databinding as:

```
buildFeatures { dataBinding true }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove this line: `implementation "androidx.room:room:$roomVersion"` . After that the application builds successfully.